# Oracle spatial Update sentence with sdo_nn "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: oracle11g, spatial-query

I am trying to get the closest point geometry element to another point, both indexed. This is the sql sentence:

'''

```
UPDATE table_A a  
SET a.fieldF = (SELECT B.fieldM, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) DIST  FROM Table_A  A, Table_B  B 
WHERE 
((SDO_NN(A.geometry, B.geometry, 'SDO_NUM_RES=1',1)='TRUE')) AND 
(B.fieldc='string1' OR B.fieldc='string2') ORDER BY DIST)

WHERE
(A.fieldF = NULL);'''
```

with this sentence I get the follow error:

**Error in te command line:7 Column:6
Error SQL: ORA-00907:
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"** but all the parenthesis are correctly closed, and If i am reading correctly, I have to break the word A.fieldF (line:7 Column:6)

What I'm doing bad?

Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

Really this error:  "missing right parenthesis"  is not correct, because really doesn't miss a parenthesis, this error is caused by a wrong write in the sentence, In this case
**"SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) DIST"**, is taken like an other field, and obviously i can't put two fields in another one

```
SET a.fieldF = (SELECT B.fieldM, SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) DIST
```

Here is an answer to this error in this case posted by the user https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot:

[I need only one unique result in Oracle sdo_nn Update sentence ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166469/i-need-only-one-unique-result-in-oracle-sdo-nn-update-sentence)